# Solve $ UA = B$, given $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1\end{bmatrix}$

I want a matrix $U$ that will transform $A$ to $B$, for example $U = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ will work, but how can I algorithmically work out $U$ in general?

Comment: In general, there will be an infinite number of solutions. To find just one, just write out what the matrix needs to satisfy to get a system of linear equations.

Comment: Since $U$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, you can specify up to $2$ linearly independent vectors $A_1, A_2$ and $2$ vectors $B_1, B_2$ and demand that $UA_1 = B_1$ and $UA_2 = B_2$, and only then would it be possible to find a unique $U$. Since you've skipped the second demand, each hypothetical choice you could've made of $A_2$ and $B_2$ would give you a different $U$ (sure, some choices would give the same $U$, but still), so there are a lot of fitting $U$'s out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\\vdots\\b_n\end{pmatrix},M=\begin{pmatrix}m_{1,1}&\cdots& m_{1,n}\\\vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\m_{n,1}&\cdots &m_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$

You want to find $M$ so that $B=MA$ which means that you want $\forall i \in\{1,\dots,n\}, b_i=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n m_{i,k}a_k$.

In the special case where $A=0_n$, we can only do that if $B=0_n$ since for any $M$, $M0_n=0_n$.

Now if $A\not=0_n$, we have a $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ so that $a_j\not = 0$. Then if we take $m_{i,k}=0$ for $k\not = j$ and $m_{i,j}=\frac{b_i}{a_j}$ then we get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n m_{i,k}a_k=m_{i,j}a_j=\frac{b_i}{a_j}a_j=b_i$ so we get the equality we wanted.

Comment: Is this implemented in python (or something else) somewhere? I don't mind writing it myself, but why re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I implemented, I think it works : https://gist.github.com/eoinmurray/6222174. I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$U \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is equal to the first column of $U$.  So we want the first column of $U$ to be $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Alternatively, we want to find a matrix $U = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ such that
\begin{align}
a\cdot 1 + b \cdot 0 &= 0, \\
c \cdot 1 + d \cdot 0 &= 1.
\end{align}
This tells us that $a = 0$ and $c = 1$.  $b$ and $d$ could be anything.